# Openstack with no fixed range

Tags: networking, openstack

I test-drove various Openstack installations (devstack, offical guides and so on) on VM's and me&my devs love it, so we acquired the HW to set a small production cluster (3 IBM x3650, 4 ethernets each, 128GB RAM and a RAID5 of 10TB in one of them).

Now, I have no problem at assigning IP ranges in my network; giving a private and a public IP to the instances is an extra burden. I want to have the VM's to access the public network directly, pretty much ESXi style (I have DHCP and DNS on the network of course). Is there a way to configure quantum in such a way that vm's get straight away a public IP? I don't mind routing the traffic thru the controller, although it could be a nice option to use the extra interfaces on each compute node to route VM traffic (again, I'm spoiled by VMWare).

If you don't know the answer, can you point me to resource and/or experts/consultants specialized in Openstack? Thanks!

Comment: If noone answer here I'd suggest you ask at https://launchpad.net/quantum .